# How Build New Golang Console App in a Main Go App?

Tags: go, build

How Build New Golang Console App in a Main Go App?
mean on a system without go compilers with main app.

example :

> $go build main.go//this is main app (***i dont know how make this!***)
>
> ./main file.go

and after this , build `file.go` and save as `file`.
also can change `OS,ARCH` in main.go..

how can make this?

Comment: https://golang.org/ has download links and documentation

Comment: yes , but i want without go compilers. and just a main GO app.

Comment: You need the go compilers to build a go app.

Comment: so golang not have a pkg for build?

Comment: A pkg as in apt-get or yum or something similar? Yes, those usually exist too

Comment: example : https://github.com/caixw/gobuild , https://github.com/ahmetb/govvv , https://github.com/songgao/colorgo

Comment: Those need the core tools installed to use

Comment: go have a portable version? mean not install go, but can use from go.(example `/home/guest/go-portable/go help`)

Comment: go is a compiler toolchain. It compiles native executables, you don't need go installed to run a compiled go protram, only to compile or run a go file. However, to build an app you need to install the packages

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have go on your system, you can use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) to build image with your program and run it in container